# If G has a KAK decomposition then does TG have a KAK decomposition?

Tags: lie-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group. If $G$ has a KAK decomposition then does the tangent bundle $TG$ admit an analogue where $K$ is replaced with $TK$ and $A$ is replaced with $TA$?

The tangent bundle admits a natural group structure. Write an element of it as $(1 + \varepsilon t) g$ where $t \in \mathfrak g$ and $g \in G$, and $\varepsilon$ formally squares to $0$. We have that:

$$(1 + \varepsilon t)g \cdot (1+\varepsilon t')g' = (1 + \varepsilon (t + gt'g^{-1}))gg' = (1 + \varepsilon(t + \operatorname{ad}_gt'))gg'.$$

So in other words, it has the group structure $G \rtimes_{\phi} \mathfrak g$, where $\mathfrak g$ has the additive group structure and $\phi = \operatorname{Ad}$.

It looks like the answer should be yes, but I don't know what methods could be used to prove this. The KAK decomposition is not in general differentiable, continuous or unique.

Comment: In any case from a map $f\colon X\to Y$ you get a map $Tf \colon TX \to TY$. Even if $f$ is surjective, $Tf$ may fail to be surjective. Q: When is $Tf$ surjective?

Comment: @orangeskid A condition is that $f'$ must never be zero. But what does this have to do with that?

Comment: @orangeskid Are you said that the surjective map from KAK to $G$, if its derivative is always of non-zero determinant, should generalise to a surjection from $TK\times TA \times TK$ to $TG$? Are you saying to use the inverse function theorem?

Comment: $Tf$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is a  surjective submersion. Well is the map $K\times A \times K \to G$ a [submersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics))?  I think it isn't, reason being that it does not have a section. Or, as you said, you cannot decompose smoothly as $KAK$. It is not a submersion at diagonal matrices $a$ with some equal entries. The determinant is $0$ there ( map between spaces of equal dimension). Away from those $a$ it is a submersion.  In the $GL$ or $SL$ case that means distinct singular values

Comment: @orangeskid Is that really an if and only if? It seems like just an "if". Not sure

Comment: @orangeskid In the GL case, I believe that my claim is actually correct. I think your method of proof simply can't detect it